# Jquery Dynamically Added Row Numbers

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table which users can add dynamically rows.
I tried to implement auto row increment with jquery.

I couldn't make it start with index 1,
After adding 2nd row it starts to add in order,
While removing in order it is ok but when we remove from middle it doesn't change the number order.

I'm using this code to increase

```
var i=1;

$('.form_id').each(function(){
    $(this).text(i);
    i++;
});
```

You can see the live example here, it will be more explanatory
[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFWU7/)

It should start automatically from index 1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is your class naming.  see this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZFWU7/5/

by naming both the td and the input `.form_id` you're iterating over all of them.

```
 $('td.form_id').each(function(i){
        $(this).text(i+1);
    });
```

make your selector more specific

per your comment, i would separate your "ordering" function into its own explicitly defined function rather than making that behavior a part of two anonomys functions.  You're not following the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) rule very well. I've rewritten your code in a cleaner more maintainable fashion below (from the fiddle). This is only slightly better.  Declaring functions in the global namespace isn't a very good practice.  It would be better to namespace your groups of 'controllers'.  http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-line").click(addRow);
});

function updateRowOrder(){
 $('td.form_id').each(function(i){
        $(this).text(i+1);
            });
}

function addRow(){
    var template = $('#template'),
    id = 0;

    if(!template.is(':visible'))
    {
        template.show();
        return;
    }
    var row = template.clone();
    template.find("input:text").val("");
    row.attr('id', 'row_' + (++id));
    template.before(row);
    var i=1;
    updateRowOrder(); 
    $('.form-fields').on('click', '.remove', removeRow);

}

function removeRow(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if(row.attr('id') == 'template')
    {
        row.hide();
    }
    else
    {
        row.remove();
    }
    updateRowOrder(); 
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But how about starting directly from 1? I mean no input box for first row. And also while we remove from middle it should decrease total number on list. Like when we delete #3 it lists: 1-2-4

Comment: I'm deeply sorry for answering late, but i got your point. Thanks for your great effort and the point of view for a non script guy. I have to follow documantations from the beginning.